# JSONDecodeError when trying to write to JSON file

Tags: python, json, jsondecodeerror

I have a json file where each entry has a corresponding list. This is what it looks like:

```
{
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_building_budget.txt": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data3/world_elements.png": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data3/data4/world.bmp": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/data2/world_files.pdf": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/data/world_saving_budget.jpg": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/a.txt": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/.gitignore": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_virtualenv.pth": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/LICENSE": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/WHEEL": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/RECORD": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/INSTALLER": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/top_level.txt": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/METADATA": [],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytz/tzfile.py": [],
...
}
```

I am trying to append data into that list like this:

```
with open('content-log.json', 'w+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

    for key in json_data:
        if filter in key:
            dict_tag = json_data[key]
            print(key, type(dict_tag))
            print(tag)
            dict_tag.append(tag)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that file name is correct, and that the file isn't empty?

Comment: The file name is correct and not empty. If I remove the `w+` parameter, there is no such error but I obviously can't write to it..

Comment: When you open a file in `w` mode, the file is emptied.

Comment: Use `r+` mode to open in read-write without emptying.

Comment: Do it in two steps.  Open the file for reading, read the json, close the file.  Update the structure, open the file for writing, do json.dump, close the file.  It is not trivial to manage reading and writing to a file simultaneously.

Comment: And, repeating what is becoming a recurring theme for me, you should be using a database for this.  JSON was intended for interchange and configuration, NOT for long-term data storage.

Comment: @Barmar I can't believe I glossed right over that.  Good eye!

Comment: Changing the parameter to `r+` gets rid of the error but nothing is appended to the lists..

Comment: Of course not.  Nothing gets written to the file unless you write it.  That JSON load is not "live".  It's a copy in memory.

Comment: @oo92 you're `print()`ing, not writing to the file. That's why

Comment: @DillonDavis `dict_tag.append(tag)`

Comment: See Tim Robert's remark on that

Comment: @TimRoberts So how can I actually write to it permanently? `w+` throws the above error.

Comment: If you don't want to open twice, open it in r+ mode, read, seek to the beginning, write, truncate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read, manipulate, write:

```
with open('content-log.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

for key in json_data:
    if filter in key:
        json_data[key].append(tag)

with open('content-log.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f)
```